# How to look up the IAM Actions needed for a given AWS API call?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Is there a way to look up the permissions you'll need enabled in order to make a call to the AWS API?

For example, I want to call `PutMetricAlarm` on the CloudWatch API so I should need at least the Action `cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm` Allowed on that resource. But what else is the minimum I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a **one-to-one relationship** between actions defined in the API and IAM actions.

In your example with `PutMetricAlarm`, no other permission than `cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm` is needed.

The IAM action name (the part after the `:`) is always identical to the name of the action in the API.

The prefix (the part before the `:`) is a constant for each service but is not always identical to the service name (e.g. CloudWatch Logs is `logs`, Firewall Manager is `fms`).

Also note that the prefix and the action name are **case insensitive**.

Good references:

- [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for AWS Services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_actions-resources-contextkeys.html)
- [AWS Policy Generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html)
- [Complete AWS IAM Reference (cloudonaut)](https://iam.cloudonaut.io/)